# How to solve '...is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context'? (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, network-programming, wmi

The following code produces the error:

> Error : 'CERas.CERAS' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given
>   context

Why does this error occur?

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinApp_WMI2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CERas.CERAS = new CERas.CERAS();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exception can also be raised when dealing with arrays and forgetting keyword new. (Happened in my case)

Array Syntax(C#)

```
data_type [] arrayName =  new data_type[size];
```

Answer (score 33):

Change

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        CERas.CERAS = new CERas.CERAS(); 
    }
```

to

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        CERas.CERAS c = new CERas.CERAS(); 
    }
```

Or if you wish to use it later again

change it to

```
using System.Drawing; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Windows.Forms; 

namespace WinApp_WMI2 
{ 
    public partial class Form1 : Form 
    { 
        CERas.CERAS m_CERAS;

        public Form1() 
        { 
            InitializeComponent(); 
        } 

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        m_CERAS = new CERas.CERAS(); 
    } 
} 


}
```

Answer (score 6):

CERAS is a class name which cannot be assigned. As the class implements [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) a typical usage would be:

```
using (CERas.CERAS ceras = new CERas.CERAS())
{
    // call some method on ceras
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You forgot to specify the variable name. It should be `CERas.CERAS newCeras = new CERas.CERAS();`

Answer (score 0):

for me it was another problem where I wrote

```
alertScript as = alert.GetComponent<alertScript>();
```

don't use as as var name ...